Is there a way to simulate an SQL Server with C#?
I want to create a simulated SQL server where I give it a log file to simulate.
I don't want to deal with a full blown Sql server where I have to input dummy data, but a simple script(log) monkey using C# TcpClient.
It would simulate from where a Client program connects/logins to it (not actually logging in, just getting canned "login sucess"), and also send queries (but the results are from the log file so no actual table or database involved).
Currently I can only imagine making an SQL client and basically monitor the exact tcp communication between it and an actual sql server. But with how long SQL has been around I wonder if there is already solution out there so I dont have to Completely reinvent the wheel so to say.
The point is to run a released application version against the sim server to recreate the situation for whatever bug it ran into elsewhere. I have the log, which also tells me the what response was given, but not at the tcp byte array level.

Just mock your "dao" or whatever that is so it doesn't actually call sql server but generates what you want it to generate

The point is to run a released application version against the sim server to recreate the situation for whatever bug it ran into elsewhere. I have the log, which also tells me the what response was given, but not at the tcp byte array level.

OK, that sounds strange... If you know the outputs, why do you need sql server at all, just write a test against the same version as released one?

Two virtualization options: TestContainers and SQL Server on Docker. These are actually full blown SQL Server instances that you can start in a lightweight way, and when you’re done with the code,they are gone. Not exactly what I think you were asking for, but maybe even better.
